# How to use "sendDocument" method in Telegram Bot API for send a file using Java

Tags: java, http, telegram-bot

I want to send a file via Telegram Bot API, but I don't know how should I do that in Java (posting multipart/form-data) with provided `Telegram Bot HTTP API` method, `sendDocument`.

Here is my code:

```
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost upload = new HttpPost("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+Main.token+"/sendDocument?chat_id="+id);

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        File file = new File(path);

        builder.addBinaryBody(
                "document",
                new FileInputStream(file));

        HttpEntity part = builder.build();

        upload.setEntity(part);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(upload);
```

[Here are the docs.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument)

Comment: we could help better if you share part of your project source code

Comment: try to use some library, for example https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope this help you.

```
private void sendDocUploadingAFile(Long chatId, java.io.File save,String caption) throws TelegramApiException {

    SendDocument sendDocumentRequest = new SendDocument();
    sendDocumentRequest.setChatId(chatId);
    sendDocumentRequest.setNewDocument(save);
    sendDocumentRequest.setCaption(caption);
    sendDocument(sendDocumentRequest);
}
```

EDIT : 
this pages can help any one to start coding with telegram-bot api

[Telegram FAQ](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/blob/master/TelegramBots.wiki/FAQ.md)

[a good tutorial](https://github.com/MonsterDeveloper/java-telegram-bot-tutorial)

Comment: While this code may solve the asker's problem, it would be preferable to explain how it works and what are the differences between it and what the asker has tried.

Comment: @dorukayhan this question was asked 7 mouths ago. a good FAQ exist on GitHub... i think more explain not necessary.but I add this FAQ address.thank you for your hint.